# dismissViewControllerAnimated is called but ViewController is not dismissed on device but work fine on the similator, why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have a main `UITableViewController` and a button to go to the settings, on settings i have another button to go back to the main view. this works fine on the simulator but when i test on the device, the app doesn't work. the button on the settings to go back to the main view don't work.

i have no idea why this is working fine on the simulator and don't work on the device. both have the same ios version.

```
- (IBAction)CancelCreation{

   // [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   // [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [viewControllerMain.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
   // UIViewController *parentController = self.presentingViewController;
  //  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//    [self.view.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

all the comment lines are attemps i make to see if works but didn't work. On de simulator all work fine but on the device nothing work. maybe is something wronk because i use ARC.

I use a segue to go from the main viewcontroller to the new controller. On the new controller i use

```
- (IBAction)CancelCreation{ 
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

to close the viewcontroller. I guess this works halfway, i mean the view don't respon anymore but didn't dissapear.

the weird part is, this works one time and now don't work.

I only have an ipad to test the app so i make the app iphone only and test if work on the device. today i make the app universal again, and tested on the device, all work fine. I have two diferent storyboards one for the iphone and one for the ipad. Maybe this is the problem i'm using a diferent kind of segue with the same name on a diferent storyboard. i don't know.

Comment: It would really help diagnose the problem if you'd include some relevant code in your question.

Comment: Is the UITableViewController being shown modally?

Comment: Try this in your button touch up handler. -(void)click { [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; }

Comment: @0x7fffffff you're right, i will add some code, when i have some time. my big question is why is working on simulator and don't work on the device.

Comment: @cms24es Sorry, but it's really hard to say without first seeing the code. When you get the chance, post the code for how you present the controller and how you're attempting to dismiss it.

Comment: @0x7fffffff your are right but i don't know what code i have to add. i use storyoard to present the controller so i don't know what code i use to present the controller.

Comment: The IBAction you've shown should be right if you are indeed presenting the controller modally. One more thing, can you add a screenshot showing the attributed of the segue.

Comment: @0x7fffffff sorry but i can't upload a photo because i'm new here.

Comment: A few things to check: Are both the simulator and the device the same OS? Have you tried debugging the code to make sure the objects are what you expect them to be (i.e. Is self.presentingViewController your main view controller?)? Are you displaying this table view controller modally?

Comment: @groomsy i'm not sure what you mean by modally, i use a segue and the style is modal and the transition is covert vertical. the weired part is the ipad version work fine is just the iphone version, the version who didn't work. i try a simple dismissmodalviewcontrollerAnimated and work fine on the ipad but not  with the iphone version.